# Estoy empezando a trabajar con java, soy un poco nuevo en el lennguaje y al momento de correr un proyecto en Maven me mando error compilacion

Tags: java, maven, netbeans-8.2, jar, maven-compiler-plugin

cd C:\Curso\Java\Encapsulamiento; "JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221" cmd /c """C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.0.2\java\maven\bin\mvn.bat" -Dmaven.ext.class.path="C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.0.2\java\maven-nblib\netbeans-eventspy.jar" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 clean install""
Scanning for projects...

---

### Building Encapsulamiento 1.0-SNAPSHOT

--- maven-clean-plugin:2.4.1:clean (default-clean) @ Encapsulamiento ---
Deleting C:\Curso\Java\Encapsulamiento\target

--- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:resources (default-resources) @ Encapsulamiento ---
[debug] execute contextualize
Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Curso\Java\Encapsulamiento\src\main\resources

--- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) @ Encapsulamiento ---
Compiling 2 source files to C:\Curso\Java\Encapsulamiento\target\classes

--- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:testResources (default-testResources) @ Encapsulamiento ---
[debug] execute contextualize
Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Curso\Java\Encapsulamiento\src\test\resources

--- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ Encapsulamiento ---
Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date

--- maven-surefire-plugin:2.10:test (default-test) @ Encapsulamiento ---
No tests to run.
Surefire report directory: C:\Curso\Java\Encapsulamiento\target\surefire-reports

---

### T E S T S

Results :

Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

--- maven-jar-plugin:2.3.2:jar (default-jar) @ Encapsulamiento ---
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-archiver/2.4.2/maven-archiver-2.4.2.pom

Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-archiver/2.0.1/plexus-archiver-2.0.1.pom

---

### BUILD FAILURE

### Total time: 6.228s
Finished at: Mon Jul 13 21:36:38 CDT 2020
Final Memory: 13M/117M

Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin:2.3.2:jar (default-jar) on project Encapsulamiento: Execution default-jar of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin:2.3.2:jar failed: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin:2.3.2 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to collect dependencies for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin:jar:2.3.2 (): Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven:maven-archiver:jar:2.4.2: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven:maven-archiver:pom:2.4.2 from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Failed to transfer file: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-archiver/2.4.2/maven-archiver-2.4.2.pom. Return code is: 501 , ReasonPhrase:HTTPS Required. -> [Help 1]

To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginResolutionException

Comment: Hola Oliver. Puedes editar tu pregunta y agregar tu pom por favor

Comment: Creo que sé cuál es el problema, pero necesito ver el pom para estar seguro.